# BAD_ACCESS when calling Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, exc-bad-access

I have class A and class B.I am calling class B from class A.Here my problem is width and height of class A is depending on class B.when `sizeForScrollView` property (class B property) changed i want notification.everything is working fine.But when i am reloading class A at that time it is crashing from class B notification line.

**Here is code :**

**class A**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (changeContentSize) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
-(void)changeContentSize{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);
    self.aSubjectView.frame = CGRectMake(frameForView.origin.x, frameForView.origin.y, frameForView.size.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);

}
```

**class B**

```
CGRect rect;
rect.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
rect.size.height = heightForSubject + 10;
rect.origin = self.frame.origin;
sizeForScrollView = rect.size;
NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
```

Please help me.Thanking you.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am reloading class A at that time it is crashing from class B notification line"? What do you mean by "reloading"? And what line do you get the BAD_ACCESS on?

Comment: i have reload button so user can reload component.and it is crashing from  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];

Comment: That's surprising. Can you post more of the relevant code? Also, I am still not sure what you mean by reloading. Do you mean the component is having some of its values refreshed after reading from some external data store? If so, how is this happening?

Comment: reloading means if user has edited something in component or did some action and then after he wants to go on initial stage.so thats the why i put reload button.that will reload everything.

Comment: Well, I (and I think others) would need to see more of the code to understand your situation better. BAD_ACCESS means that you are addressing memory that you have already released, so I would try putting in some breakpoints and seeing if the variables have the values you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure instances of class A are removing themselves as observers on dealloc. Otherwise if you release an instance, the notification center will still try to talk to it after it's been released, causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.

If you're not using ARC, that would look something like this (in class A):

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc]; // Take this line out if you are using ARC
}
```

This is necessary because adding an object as an observer does not increment its retain count. The notification center doesn't take ownership of the observer or do anything to track whether it's still around or not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the observer for "MyNotification" in viewDidUnload

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```